# How to Convert 18 char Id to 15 char Id using substring in Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, id

I have a trigger where i am assigning ID to a cusotm field like below -

```
D.customfield__c = acc.Id;
```

The ID is coming as 00P28000000EwpjEA0

But i need only 00P28000000Ewpj 15 char. Is there is a way to use substring in apex trigger. I can't use formula field.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All you need to do is convert the `Id` to a `String` and you can call [`substring(startIndex, endIndex)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substring_2) on it.

The following should work:

```
D.customfield__c = String.valueOf(acc.Id).substring(0, 15);
```

Answer (score 8):

Following Spring '21 release, we can now use a dedicated function on the System.Id class called `to15()`.

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_nc.htm&release=230&type=5):

> Convert an 18-character Id value to a 15-character case-sensitive
> string. Use the to15() method in the System.Id class. This method uses
> the case-sensitivity checksum in the 18-character Id value to fix any
> mangled casing and returns a 15-character case-sensitive string.

Example:

```
    String Id_15_char = '0D5B000001DVM9t';
    String Id_18_char = '0D5B000001DVM9tkAh';
    ID testId = Id_18_char;
    System.assertEquals(testId.to15(),Id_15_char);
```