# how to split string based on particular digit in apex?

Tags: apex

Hi i will get 18 digit recordId in batch apex..But i have 15 digit Id.When id tried  to compare both ids getting null value.How to get 15 digit id from 18 digit id.

```
String id = 'a0P4E0000030HzNXAU';
i need only 'a0P4E0000030HzN'
```

Comment: possible duplicate- [How to Convert 18 char Id to 15 char Id using substring in Apex trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83349/how-to-convert-18-char-id-to-15-char-id-using-substring-in-apex-trigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

> String id ='a0P4E0000030HzNXAU';
>
> String Str= id.substring(0, 15);

**Signature**

```
public String substring(Integer startIndex, Integer endIndex)
```

Returns a new String that begins with the character at the specified zero-based startIndex and extends to the character at endIndex - 1.

**Parameters**

- startIndex
  Type: Integer
- endIndex
  Type: Integer
- Return Value
  Type: String

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your string values to ID values; then it does not matter if you use the 15- or 18-character version:

```
Id a = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1].Id;
String b = ((String)a).left(15);
System.debug(a);
System.debug(b);
// If either side is type Id, comparison is done as Id
System.debug(a == b);
```

Output:

> (18624874)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|00150000019w4KXAAY 09:03:52.1
>
> (18697954)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|00150000019w4KX 09:03:52.1
>
> (18894321)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|true 09:03:52.1

It is far more convenient to **use the correct data type** than manually performing "conversions" by stripping off the last 3 characters. Also, string comparisons in Salesforce are **NOT** case sensitive, so you risk getting false positives:

```
System.assert('00150000019w4KX' == '00150000019w4Kx');
```